# Displaying text from from edittext to textview

Tags: java, android, button, android-edittext

I have a weather app that requires you to take the text from a edit text field and display it in a text view, I'm trying to make it so when I enter a place it will generate random weather for them along with displaying their input.

I haven't tried much apart from examples online as I recently started learning android development.

```java
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

/**
 * Implementation for the main activity
 */
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    // member variable for the user provided location
    private String location;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // get the Get Forecast button
        Button btnGetForecast = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGetForecast);

        // set the click listener to the btnGetForecast Button
        btnGetForecast.setOnClickListener(this);

        EditText loc = findViewById(R.id.etLocationInput);
        location = loc.getText().toString();


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // view is the View (Button, ExitText, TextView, etc) that was clicked


        // if it was the btnGetForecast
        if (view.getId() == R.id.btnGetForecast){

        }
    }
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/tvTitle" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvInstructions"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter a location below for the forecast" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etLocationInput"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnGetForecast"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Get Forecast" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvLocationDisplay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="The weather in " />

</LinearLayout>
```

I expect the app to show input from user and display it in text view

Comment: init your tvLocationDisplay in your class android set it.

Answer (score 0):

This line in your onCreate: 'location = loc.getText().toString()' will only get the current text in loc, which at onCreate will be an empty string.

You should look into TextWatcher: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher. This will allow you to get a callback when the text of loc changes and you can then carry out your weather generation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, all you need to do is to add this code in onClick method:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    // view is the View (Button, ExitText, TextView, etc) that was clicked


    // if it was the btnGetForecast
    if (view.getId() == R.id.btnGetForecast){
        String text = loc.getText().toString();
        yourTextView.setText(text);
    }
}
```

And don't forget to make view variables global, so you could access them outside onCreate method, without using findViewById() again.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private TextView yourTextView;
private EditText loc;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // get the Get Forecast button
    Button btnGetForecast = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGetForecast);

    // set the click listener to the btnGetForecast Button
    btnGetForecast.setOnClickListener(this);

    loc = findViewById(R.id.etLocationInput);
    yourTextView = findViewById(R.id.tvLocationDisplay);


    }
 ...
}
```